# Can I use a real card instead of a test card to test a payment in "Test" mode in Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments, payment, checkout, card, stripe-test-mode

I can test payments with [the test cards](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards) below in `test` mode in Stripe:

[image]

Now, can I test payments with **my own real cards** in `test` mode in Stripe?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use real cards in `test` mode. You'll get a decline error if you enter a real card to complete a `test` mode payment.